# A verb for loutish, boorish, uncouth behavior

Tags: grammar, verbs

Is there a single verb for someone behaving boorishly, in particular someone talking in loutish fashion? I googled it, and there are many nouns as well as off-noun adjectives like "loutish", but no verbs, although google translate from my native language suggests "lout" as a verb.

What do you say to someone who talks boorishly to you, as in "Don't ___ to me!"

Comment: It would depend on the nature of what was being said and the manner in which it was being said. I don't think there is one verb. "Mouth off" that might approximate in some contexts - https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mouth%20%28off%29

Comment: @Greybeard No, that is not it. If someone talks to you, denigrating, slandering you in an offensive manner, or maybe a kid talking back to his parent, what would you say they do as a single verb, and how do you use a verb to tell them to stop doing it, like "Stop denigrating me!" But "denigrating" is not exactly the word I am looking for.

Comment: Hmm... If they were being impolite to their parents, I wouldn't say anything - it's the parents' problem.

Comment: The slang is “diss,” although one of many. “Be rude” would be standard.

Comment: 'Act out' is the common term for disruptive behaviour, used especially in the US and in the educational domain. But as it is a single lexeme but not a single word, and as it doesn't fit your template sentence, i'll only expand on it in an answer if you OK it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two candidates: *bluster* and *mouth off*

> bluster =
>
> to speak in a loud, angry, or offended way, usually with little effect
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bluster)

*bluster* has come into greater use in recent years (look at google ngram) perhaps because of the ways in which modes of political expression have changed.

Your answer: "Don't bluster at me."

If you prefer to answer in the same low register as the speaker I rather like the colloquial but effective "mouth off"

> mouth off =
>
> to speak in a rude or offensive way to someone:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mouth-off-to-at-sb)

Your answer: "Stop mouthing off at me!"

Comment: Or if you want to slide even further down the scale you can use "gob off" so you say "Stop gobbing off at me". Maybe I'm just a bit more loutish than you. :-)

Comment: Funny, I would use *mouth off **to***.   “Don’t you mouth off to me young man.”

Comment: @BoldBen and Jim You both cheer me. And no you are not loutish - just unusually receptive to a wide spectrum of expression! Thanks

Comment: I like "bluster". Although Google Translate, when translating to my native language, suggest meanings like "boast", "brag", and also "threaten", neither of which is what I am looking for. But Google's "define bluster" is close to what I am searching for: "talk in a loud, aggressive, or indignant way with little effect." Google needs to clean up and combine its databases for Google Define and Google Translate ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**smart off**

*To talk back to someone in a rude, impertinent, and disrespectful manner*.

> You're going to get suspended again if you keep smarting off to your teachers like that.

[The Free Dictionary]

**sass**

> To talk impudently to

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: Is this expression common in any particular country?I don't recall having heard it before.

Comment: I thought it was a common phrasal verb.

Comment: I have never heard or read "smart off" in the United Kingdom.